# Reading from a Serial Port with Ruby

Tags: ruby, serial-port

I'm trying to use ruby to do a simple read + write operation to a serial port.

This is the code I've got so far. I'm using the `serialport` gem.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'serialport'

ser = SerialPort.new("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600, 8, 1, SerialPort::NONE)

ser.write "ab\r\n"
puts ser.read
```

But the script hangs when it is run.

Comment: @psp
Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: And after read, is not necessary some close?

Answer (score 9):

I had the problem to.  It's because using ser.read tells Ruby to keep reading forever and Ruby never stops reading and thus hangs the script.  The solution is to only read a particular amount of characters.

So for example:

```
ser.readline(5)
```

Answer (score 5):

To echo what user968243 said, that ser.read call is going to wait for EOF.  If your device is not sending EOF, you will wait forever.  You can read only a certain number of characters as suggested.

Your device may be ending every response with an end of line character.  Try reading up to the next carriage return:

```
response = ser.readline("\r")
response.chomp!
print "#{response}\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem and found a solution.  Use the Ruby IO method readlines.

```
puts ser.readlines
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your device is waiting for some input. Check this answer and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10534407/1006863

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the #read_timeout value for the serial port.  Note that the same thing can be done for a write operation using the #write_timeout value.